# chai Error: unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, mocha.js, chai

stack: nodejs4, chai,jdom. The objective is to write a test that interrogates the HTML of a URL in a web application which is only accessible over SSL in the corporate intranet.

I am writing a mocha test using jsdom and I get the SSL certificate error:

```
    { Error: unable to verify the first certificate
  at Error (native)
  at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1060:38)
  at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
  at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
  at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:584:8)
  at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:416:38)
 code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE' }
```

I have the following test code:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var jsdom  = require('jsdom');
var expect = chai.expect;

https = require('https');
fs = require('fs');

var cas = require('ssl-root-cas/latest').inject().addFile('test/ssl/key.pem').addFile('test/ssl/server.crt');
//process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
https.globalAgent.options.ca = cas;

jsdom.env(
 "https://www.example.com",
 ['https://www.example.com/jquery-1.10.2.js'],
  function(err, window) {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("contents of the research project input box is:", window.$("#field_cell_1840 input.custom-combobox-input").text());
    }
  }
);
```

I have generated the keys in test/ssl like this:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -keyout key.pem -out csr.pem
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in csr.pem -signkey key.pem -out server.crt
```

I have followed various threads and tried suggestions in https://github.com/coolaj86/node-ssl-root-cas including bad ideas such as the use of process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"

When I do a curl -vk https://www.example.com then I get the following output:

```
ac2f15@UOS-012145  ~/git/NodeJS/test (master)
$ curl -vk https://www.example.com
* Rebuilt URL to: www.example.com
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
*   Trying 192.168.168.116...
* Connected to www.example.com (192.168.168.116) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.0 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.0 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.0 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.0 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.0 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.0 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.0 / DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*        subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; CN=sitepublisher-dev.soton.ac.uk
*        start date: Dec  9 00:00:00 2014 GMT
*        expire date: Dec  8 23:59:59 2017 GMT
*        issuer: C=NL; ST=Noord-Holland; L=Amsterdam; O=TERENA; CN=TERENA SSL CA 2
*        SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: srv00700.soton.ac.uk
> User-Agent: curl/7.46.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Mon, 10 Oct 2016 16:09:05 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5
< Location: https://www.example.com/
< Content-Length: 358
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
<
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
```

My question is, is there someone who has done a successful chai test using jdom on a https URL ? If so, could you please share your experience with me?